# Concatenating files with python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I'm learning data science with "Python for Data Analysis".

And I'd like to concatenate text files into one large dataframe.
Here is the code provided by the author but it doesn't work on my Mac OS X Yosemite..
Could someone help?

```
import pandas as pd

names1880 = pd.read_csv('ch02/names/yob1880.txt', names=['name', 'sex', 'births'])
names1880.groupby('sex').births.sum()
years = range(1880,2010)

pieces = []
columns = ['name','sex','births']

for year in years:
    path = 'ch02/names/yob%d.txt' % year
    frame = pd.read_csv(path,names=columns)
names = pd.concat(pieces,ignore_index=True)
```

The output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-76cd5bf6ba3e> in <module>()
     14     frame = pd.read_csv(path,names=columns)
     15 
---> 16 names = pd.concat(pieces,ignore_index=True)
     17 
     18 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/merge.pyc in concat(objs, axis, join, join_axes, ignore_index, keys, levels, names, verify_integrity)
    927                        ignore_index=ignore_index, join=join,
    928                        keys=keys, levels=levels, names=names,
--> 929                        verify_integrity=verify_integrity)
    930     return op.get_result()
    931 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/merge.pyc in __init__(self, objs, axis, join, join_axes, keys, levels, names, ignore_index, verify_integrity)
    972 
    973         if len(objs) == 0:
--> 974             raise Exception('All objects passed were None')
    975 
    976         # consolidate data

Exception: All objects passed were None
```

Comment: This code seems to be missing `pieces.append(frame)` at the end of your for-loop.

Comment: Ah I see. It was an easy mistake.. Thanks!